# Excluding @aws-sdk packages from the output of serverless package command in Serverless Framework

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I am using the Serverless Framework to deploy my AWS Lambda functions. I want to exclude the "@aws-sdk" packages from the build file generated by the serverless package command. I have tried using both the exclude property and forceExclude option in my serverless.yml file, but the "@aws-sdk" packages still appear in the build file.

Here's my current configuration in serverless.yml:

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
  # I have also tried using forceExclude:
  # forceExclude:
  #   - node_modules/aws-sdk/**

functions:
  # function configurations...
```

I have double-checked that the `exclude` property is correctly set, and I have restarted the deployment process multiple times, but the `@aws-sdk` packages keep showing up in the build file.

Is there any other approach or configuration option that I'm missing? How can I effectively `exclude` the `@aws-sdk` packages from the output of the serverless package command? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, serverless-esbuild excludes `aws-sdk` version 2. If you are using version 3, the folder name is different. It is `@aws-sdk`, so you must add this on your configuration

```
custom:
  esbuild:
    exclude:
      - "@aws-sdk"
```